# PHP - access attributes and methods of outside object

Tags: php

I'm new to php and I was wondering why this doesn't work:

```
class A {
      private $containigObject;
      public function __construct($containigObject){
        $this->containigObject = $containigObject;
      }
      public function functionThatAccessOutsideObject(){
        //...
        $this->containgObject->b = 2;
        //...
      }
}

class B {
      public $b = 1;
      public function someFunction(){
        //...
        $a = new A($this);
        $a->functionThatAccessOutsideObject();
        //...
      }
}

$b = new B();
$b->someFunction();
```

I'm trying to use attributes and methods from Class B in Class A

Comment: Your code does work! http://ideone.com/rUoXCI

Comment: I can change $b only in constructor of A not it's methods. When I do var_dump $b it says object(B)#1 (1) { ["b"]=> int(1) }

Comment: You ought to share your error messages. If the code above is pasted from your actual code, your problem is spelling. Your private var is spelled differently in declaration and use.

Comment: OMG. You're right, I see it now. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
  private $**containigObject**;
  public function __construct($containigObject){
    $this->containigObject = $containigObject;
  }
  public function functionThatAccessOutsideObject(){
    //...
    $this->**containgObject**->b = 2;
    //...
  }
```

}